# Pagination Django Rest Framework POST

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, pagination

I'm trying to send a POST request through an endpoint with generic APIVIEW class. The response rendered through this post request needs to be paginated. The limit and offset parameters for pagination are passed in the same POST request body. How can same be implemented using the LimitOffsetPagination. I have seen seen various examples of pagination in GET requests but no luck on POST request.

Comment: Humm... I don't think you can get that out of the box with POST. Why don't you make a GET request to get the data?

Comment: @luistm i cant literally do much by changing that. Actually it's an API posting something and returning all the data that already existed along with this current data.